can't ping IPv6 local link
I am new to IPv6 world. I feel like I should be able to do this but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have a GNS3 server deployed in Digtal Ocean. I have deployed a Mikrotik and connected it to the eth0 port on the cloud interface.
On GNS3 server, when I run IP address show,  I get a bunch of results. For security purposes I will redact any public IP and just show the link local address of my eth0 interface
 eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether da:b7:8d:c8:a3:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet <redacted> brd 143.198.159.255 scope global eth0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 10.48.0.31/16 brd 10.48.255.255 scope global eth0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 <redacted> scope global
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
**inet6 fe80::d8b7:8dff:fec8:a310/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever**

My mikrotik whos Eth1 interface is connected to the Eth0 interface of the Cloud node, I get the following ipv6 address
[admin@MikroTik] > ipv6/address/print
Flags: D - DYNAMIC; L - LINK-LOCAL
Columns: ADDRESS, INTERFACE, ADVERTISE
# ADDRESS INTERFACE ADVERTISE
**0 D ::1/128 lo no
1 DL fe80::ec9:22ff:fe9d:0/64 ether1 no**

I also ran a ip -6 route list and here is the results I got.
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2604:a880:4:1d0::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev tun1194 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via <redacted> dev eth0 proto static metric 1024 pref medium

When I attempt to ping these devices on the link local interface, I simply get a timeout. I am sure I am making mistake here but any help would be appreciate.

Are you properly including the Zone ID when you use link-local addressing? It is required because all IPv6 interfaces in a device use the same link local network, so you must distinguish which interface you mean with the Zone ID. The format of that is OS specific. Unfortunately, MikroTik is off-topic here.

Thanks for your comment. It seems like by Zone ID, you must mean the interface name. Yes you can't ping a link local address unless you specify the interface.
I am going to remove the Mikrotik and just spin an Ubuntu and connect them the same way. Will report back on my results. Thanks for your help

I removed the Mikrotik and added an Ubuntu Server. Had the same issue. Then i added another Ubuntu and connected both of them together to see if i can ping each other on IPv6 and I could.
I am starting to think there has to be a setting on these Droplets that is preventing me from getting a response back.

Yes, unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers/VMs are off-topic here. You could ask about that on [sf] for a business network.

Everyone makes this mistake. ping [address]%[interface]

Because every interface on a host uses the same link-local network (/fe80::/64), using link-local addressing for traffic requires you to specify a Zone ID with the destination address in order for the host to determine which interface to use. This also applies on hosts with only one physical address.
As Ricky explained in his comment: ping [address]%[interface]. What he shows as [interface] is the IPv6 Zone ID. Unfortunately, the exact Zone ID syntax is not defined, and each OS uses something different, sometime even between OS versions. You need to determine what the syntax for that is on your hosts.
The Zone ID is only local to the host on which you use it; it is not sent in a packet. I have seen where people are trying to use the Zone ID of the destination host, but it is for the source host because it is on local to the source host.
